# Is there a way to provide n counts for a ggplot bar graph that uses a factor variable with the fill aesthetic?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working with a set of data that uses a factor variable that has "Yes" and "No" as levels of response. I've figured out how to create a bar graph based on this data, but I can't seem to get an n/count of each bar to work with the graph.

While the y-axis is "count", it's showing the proportion of yes and no as I intend it to. However, when I try to add a line to label the count, it goes far above the bars at the actual "count" on the y-axis.

[image]

The figure above is created with the code:

```
  gun_oppo_plot <- ggplot(data = gun_survey_oppo, aes(x = condition, fill = gun_DV)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", na.rm = TRUE) + theme_bw()
```

When I try to add a line such as   `geom_text(aes(label=..count..),stat="count")`, I get the following figure:
[image]

Is there a way to get the same counts as in the lower figure, while maintaing the first one's focus on y from (0:1) and having the counts be on the bars themselves?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Data for replication:

```
structure(list(condition = structure(c(4L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
3L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 
1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 
5L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 
2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 
1L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 
5L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
4L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
2L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 
1L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 
2L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), 
    gun_DV = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(2L, 
4L, 8L, 9L, 12L, 13L, 17L, 21L, 25L, 26L, 28L, 31L, 35L, 37L, 
44L, 46L, 47L, 49L, 52L, 53L, 56L, 59L, 66L, 71L, 74L, 76L, 79L, 
81L, 83L, 85L, 94L, 97L, 98L, 104L, 109L, 110L, 114L, 116L, 117L, 
120L, 122L, 124L, 129L, 130L, 133L, 136L, 138L, 144L, 147L, 152L, 
157L, 158L, 162L, 167L, 169L, 171L, 178L, 188L, 195L, 198L, 203L, 
206L, 209L, 211L, 213L, 217L, 219L, 222L, 225L, 228L, 230L, 231L, 
235L, 237L, 240L, 256L, 257L, 259L, 260L, 262L, 267L, 269L, 271L, 
272L, 278L, 279L, 285L, 289L, 294L, 295L, 297L, 299L, 300L, 302L, 
304L, 310L, 311L, 314L, 318L, 319L, 321L, 323L, 326L, 328L, 333L, 
341L, 342L, 343L, 348L, 357L, 359L, 360L, 363L, 364L, 372L, 375L, 
377L, 379L, 387L, 391L, 392L, 394L, 397L, 399L, 401L, 404L, 405L, 
411L, 416L, 418L, 421L, 423L, 427L, 428L, 430L, 434L, 438L, 446L, 
454L, 456L, 458L, 460L, 463L, 465L, 477L, 479L, 482L, 485L, 490L, 
493L, 497L, 500L, 501L, 503L, 507L, 512L, 514L, 516L, 519L, 522L, 
525L, 531L, 533L, 539L, 541L, 543L, 552L, 555L, 556L, 559L, 563L, 
566L, 569L, 570L, 572L, 574L, 576L, 579L, 581L, 584L, 589L, 590L, 
596L, 598L, 599L, 603L, 607L, 609L, 611L, 613L, 618L, 620L, 621L, 
624L, 625L, 628L, 629L, 638L, 641L, 644L, 645L, 647L, 651L, 653L, 
658L, 663L, 665L, 666L, 675L, 677L, 678L, 680L, 686L, 693L, 697L, 
699L, 700L, 704L, 705L, 708L, 709L, 713L, 715L, 717L, 718L, 721L, 
724L, 726L, 728L, 735L, 739L, 741L, 748L, 750L, 753L, 756L, 758L, 
759L, 762L, 769L, 772L, 780L, 782L, 786L, 788L, 790L, 793L, 796L, 
799L, 801L, 804L, 806L, 808L, 809L, 818L, 820L, 823L, 825L, 832L, 
835L, 836L, 842L, 844L, 846L, 847L, 855L, 856L, 858L, 860L, 861L, 
865L, 867L, 872L, 875L, 876L, 878L, 884L, 887L, 891L, 893L, 896L
))
```

Comment: You just need to provide `position="fill"` argument to `geom_text`.

Comment: @yh6 is there a way using that method to also apply vjust such as in Ronak's answer so that the count display is in the center of each bar?

Comment: You can use `position=position_fill(vjust=<num>)` (Actually `position="fill"` is the abbreviation of `position=position_fill(vjust=1)`)

Answer (score 1):

There might be some way to do this within ggplot itself but here is another way where we "prepare" the data first before plotting.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

gun_survey_oppo %>%
  count(condition, gun_DV) %>%
  group_by(condition) %>%
  mutate(prop = prop.table(n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(condition, prop, fill = gun_DV, label = n)) +
  geom_col(position = "fill", na.rm = TRUE) + 
  geom_text(position = position_stack(vjust = .5)) + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]